# CGP Vertex AI notebook - turn on Secure Boot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-vertex-ai

When creating a notebook instance via GCP console, I can check a box "Turn on Secure Boot". Is it possible to turn on Secure Boot when creating the notebook using gcloud command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little involved, but [yes you can](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/shielded-vm).